# Add CMS page to topmenu only with XML

Tags: layout, cms, design

In CMS->page->Design->DesignXML

I add this:

```
<reference name="top.menu">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
<label>Home</label>
<url></url>
<title>Home</title><prepare>true</prepare>
<urlParams/>
<position>5</position>
</action>
</reference>
```

This gives an error (because of the `name="top.menu"`) but what would be the correct XML for the top menu (*not* the top.links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `top.links` instead of `top.menu` in your reference node.

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
        <label>Home</label>
        <url>/</url>
        <title>Home</title><prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>5</position>
    </action>
</reference>
```

It's not possible to simply add links to the category navigation (`top.menu` > `catalog.topnav`).
You can add child blocks to `top.menu`, since it is a `core/text_list` block, but they will be rendered before or after the `<div class="nav-container">` of the `catalog.topnav` block.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Strange that this isn't possible though. (I mean, more easily)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a block inside `top.menu` with your custom links.
Add this in your theme's `local.xml` file:

```
    <reference name="header">
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.menu.custom-links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                    <label>New Link</label>
                    <url>my-url</url>
                    <title>New Link</title>
                    <prepare>true</prepare>
                    <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
                    <position>60</position>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
```

I think this is the easiest way.